# Rails Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Rails is giving me a route error even though the route appears to
be in the route list.

The form is doing a Post to try to hit the update route on the Admin::ProductsController.
The edit route, index route, and show route work fine.

Using Rails 3.0.5 and ruby 1.9.2

Anyone have an idea?  I can't seem to see the problem.

### Error

No route matches "/admin/products/2039"

### Code from ERB File that is generating the form

```
 <%= form_for :product, @product, :url => { :action => "update" } do |f| %>
```

### Products Controller method at this point is just a stub of

```
def update
puts params.inspect
end
```

### Routes File

```
Analytics::Application.routes.draw do

  match 'login' => 'Authentication#login', :via => [:get, :post]    

  namespace :admin do
    # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
    # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
    root :to => 'AdminInterface#index', :via => :get

    resources :products  

    resources :publishers, :only => [:edit, :update]
    match 'publishers/query/:subset' => 'Publishers#index', :as => :publishers_subset, :via => [:get, :post]
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your routes, shouldn't that be

```
= form_for [:admin, @product] do |f|
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `form_for` can just be:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
```

If `@product` is an existing object then it will automatically know to go the `update` action of the `ProductsController`.